# Ubuntu Software Center 12.04 does not install software

Tags: networking, software-center, proxy

I am new to Ubuntu, and I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a computer. I am using an automatic proxy server. When I select a software package to install and input my password, the progress icon displays for a few seconds, and then it stops. I tried to install different programs, and I always had the same problem. I can browse the web with Firefox, so I know I have a network connection. I do not see any errors or anything. What should I do?

Comment: Did you configure Firefox to use the Proxy Server?

Comment: Did you config Firefox, or your computer to use the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a work around. Once you find a game you want to install, you can search for it in the terminal with (for example ** Super Tux):

```
apt-cache search Super Tux
```

Then you can install one of the names it displays by for example:

```
sudo apt-get install supertux
```

If you want to install a game from *dotdeb.com* for instance, you can open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

Make sure to leave a <kbd>Space</kbd> **after** the `-i` and then drag-and-drop the deb file you downloaded onto the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I am trying to install netbeans. If I try the command "apt-cache search netbeans" I get nothing back.

Comment: You install netbeans for the original web site. It will not be in the Software Center as its sort of "lisenced" software. http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use synaptic package manager, even though it's not as fancy as the software center. To install it type: `sudo apt-get install synaptic` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with software. It's probably a permission thing.

On my menu the command to open uses software-center with pkexec, which command without parameters defaults to superuser. It seems to have issues.

By altermint the menu command to gksu software-center I found it worked and installed programs with no problems.

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting here. I am a real beginner :)

Comment: I see - I tried gksu but when I try to look at installed software it just sits there with a rotating time icon.

Comment: When I try to execute "gksu software-center" I get a warning on the command line that says "unable to find the server at software-center.unbunto,com"

Comment: I think you did typo, should be a point instead of comma (`ubuntu,com` > `ubuntu.com`).